# Can't get react-photo-gallery to render images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hopefully this will be a quick fix but I can't see it. I'm trying to use react-photo-gallery to render images from Unsplash. The API's response is an array of objects like so:

```
{
    "id": "LBI7cgq3pbM",
    "created_at": "2016-05-03T11:00:28-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-10T11:00:01-05:00",
    "width": 5245,
    "height": 3497,
    "color": "#60544D",
    "likes": 12,
    "liked_by_user": false,
    "description": "A man drinking a coffee.",
    "user": {
      "id": "pXhwzz1JtQU",
      "username": "poorkane",
      "name": "Gilbert Kane",
      "portfolio_url": "https://theylooklikeeggsorsomething.com/",
      "bio": "XO",
      "location": "Way out there",
      "total_likes": 5,
      "total_photos": 74,
      "total_collections": 52,
      "instagram_username": "instantgrammer",
      "twitter_username": "crew",
      "profile_image": {
        "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg?q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&fit=crop&h=32&w=32",
        "medium": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg?q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&fit=crop&h=64&w=64",
        "large": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg?q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&fit=crop&h=128&w=128"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/poorkane",
        "html": "https://unsplash.com/poorkane",
        "photos": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/poorkane/photos",
        "likes": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/poorkane/likes",
        "portfolio": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/poorkane/portfolio"
      }
    },
    "current_user_collections": [ // The *current user's* collections that this photo belongs to.
      {
        "id": 206,
        "title": "Makers: Cat and Ben",
        "published_at": "2016-01-12T18:16:09-05:00",
        "updated_at": "2016-07-10T11:00:01-05:00",
        "curated": false,
        "cover_photo": null,
        "user": null
      },
      // ... more collections
    ],
    "urls": {
      "raw": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg",
      "full": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg",
      "regular": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max",
      "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&w=400&fit=max",
      "thumb": "https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&w=200&fit=max"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM",
      "html": "https://unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM",
      "download": "https://unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM/download",
      "download_location": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM/download"
    }
}
```

The react-photo-gallery component requires the array in question to be arranged like so:

```
const PHOTO_SET = [
  {
    src: 'http://example.com/example/img1.jpg',
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  },
  {
    src: 'http://example.com/example/img2.jpg',
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  }
];
```

I've managed to map through my Unsplash response and create an array specific to the react-photo-gallery one, which I've checked in the console and it's there. However, when I pass the new array to the component it doesn't pick it up. Nothing's breaking, it's just not showing at all.

My full page looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPhotos } from '../../actions/photoActions';
import { GET_CONTACTS } from '../../actions/types';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';


class Photos extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getPhotos();
  }

  render() {
    const { photos } = this.props;

    const PHOTO_SET = photos.map( (photo, i) => {
      return {
        src: photo.urls.small,
        width: 4,
        height: 3
      }
    });

    console.log(photos);
    console.log(PHOTO_SET);

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="display-3">A little gallery courtesy of <a href="">unsplash.com</a></h1>
          </div>
        <div className="gallery-row">
          <Gallery photos={PHOTO_SET} direction={"column"}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  photos: state.photo.photos
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPhotos })(Photos);
```

To clarify, the props have the data (`photos`), and the `PHOTO_SET` is holding the restructures data, but the component just isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: this url `https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg` is not working in browser. That's  the reason.

Comment: That's an interesting point, but my URLs are like this:

"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536891259032-26d57921dc41?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjM2MjcxfQ&s=66dca0ad27dcb98c99c29e39e2cb6abc"

When I take off the quote marks the images show, but still not in the component

Comment: can you post your `urls` object from the response.

Comment: If you go to https://unsplash.com/documentation#list-photos, look in the response.

Comment: Also, the https://images.unsplash.com/face-springmorning.jpg is a placeholder and doesn't work

Comment: That's the reason I'm saying share your actual response. and can you check in the networks tab if requests are being made?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180117/discussion-between-jj-mcgregor-and-murli-prajapati).